# How can I post my button value in Flask with Ajax without reshing the page?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I have a problem, I want to avoid reloading when I click on button in my flask app.
I know that there is the Ajax solution but I would like to know how I could link my buttons to an ajax function to post the button value and run my python functions link to their value.

Here are my button in html :

```
                        <div id="d_line1">
                            <button type="submit" id="bul" name="UL" value="UL">UL</button>
                            <button type="submit" id="bu" name="U" value="U">ʌ</button>
                            <button type="submit" id="bur" name="UR" value="UR">UR</button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="d_line2">
                            <button type="submit" id="bl" name="L" value="L"><</button>
                            <button type="submit" id="br" name="R" value="R">></button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="d_line3">
                            <button type="submit" id="bdl" name="DL" value="DL">DL</button>
                            <button type="submit" id="bd" name="D" value="D">v</input>
                            <button type="submit" id="bdr" name="DR" value="DR">DR</button>
                        </div>
```

my python function associated to the buttons :

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route('/interface_novapro.html', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def pilotageTour():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form.get('UL') == 'UL':
            print("Bouton Up Left reconnu")
        
        if request.form.get('U') == 'U':
            print("Bouton Up reconnu")
        
        if request.form.get('UR') == 'UR':
            print("Bouton Up Right reconnu")
        
        if request.form.get('L') == 'L':
            print("Bouton Left reconnu")
        
        if request.form.get('R') == 'R':
            print("Bouton Right reconnu")

        if request.form.get('DR') == 'DR':
            print("Bouton Down Right reconnu")
        
        if request.form.get('D') == 'D':
            print("Bouton Down reconnu")
        
        if request.form.get('DL') == 'DL':
            print("Bouton Down Left reconnu")

        if request.form.get('S') == 'S':
            print("Bouton Stop reconnu")

    return render_template("/interface_novapro.html")
```

I have some idea about how the ajax function should look like but I'm not really comfortable with javascript...

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); //to avoid reload
                $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/interface_novapro.html",
                            data: { 
                                "How can I get the value of the button tag??"
                                },
                            success: function(result) {
                                alert('ok');
                            },
                            error: function(result) {
                                alert('error');
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

If you need more information about my code, tell me!
I'm looking forward for your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're HTML is really messed up. Only `input[type="submit"]` buttons should have the `value` attribute, and no, don't add name.

Comment: The way you're handling the request in Python is very strange an unnecessarily complicated. Try googling the proper way to handle POST requests.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the value is easy using `this`:

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {
  // ...
  const valueOfButton = $(this).attr("value");
  // ...
  $.ajax({
    // ...
    data: { [$(this).attr("name")]: valueOfButton }
    // ...
  });
});
```

Comment: @K-SolyvanEar great! Would you kindly select it as the answer?